# Update Payment of existing Subscribed PayPal Users

Tags: c#, paypal, payment, paypal-subscriptions

We are using Legacy PayPal Standard Payment button for the subscription creation from the website and we have around 10000 active subscribed or recurring users as of now.

Recently we have changed the amount for the subscription.  Currently new users are subscribing with new price. But existing subscription users are still paying old amount. How can we update previous subscriptions? Is there any API available to update these existing subscriptions? There is a way for updating the subscription via dashbaord, but updating 10000 subscriptions via Dashboard is not a great idea. So Is there any better approach to update the existing subscribers payment amount?